# Using the I18n functionality in Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm having trouble with the I18n functionality in Kohana 3.3

My I18n folder structure is as follows

i18n/

- en/

  - us.php
- zh/

  - hk.php
  - cn.php

The problem I'm getting is that everywhere I read it should be possible to load the language like so `i18n::lang('en-us');` because the api states that it explodes the string on the “-” character, so the default target language “en-us” results in a search for the following files:

```
/application/i18n/en.php
/application/i18n/en/us.php
```

It only seems to load the correct language files when I use `i18n::lang('en/us');` instead of `i18n::lang('en-us');`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. These calls are equals for Kohana:

```
I18n::lang('en-us'); 
I18n::lang('en us');
I18n::lang('en_us');
```

When you use 'en/us' value, I18n will not load `i18n/en.php` file, only `i18n/en/us.php`.

I can suggest only one reason for your problems:

You are using `__()` function, which ignores translations for default language ('en-us' is hardcoded). So, when you call I18n::lang('en/us'), default language is still english, but it differs from 'en-us'. Little hack :)

You can extend I18n class with `APPPATH/classes/I18n.php` file (standard Kohana way), and  add your own version for that function:

```
// translate always!
function __($string, array $values = NULL, $lang = 'en-us')
{
    $string = I18n::get($string);

    return empty($values) ? $string : strtr($string, $values);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new to all this.
So it's like [this](http://ideone.com/nuUm76)? and I put it in `APPPATH/classes/I18n.php`?

Comment: Oh wait, stupid me haha was way too tired when I wrote that, no idea why I was thinking it was a class method.

Comment: It's not a class method, but Kohana includes the __() function in the same file as the [I18n class](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/I18n.php), so if you put it elsewhere, make sure you include that file manually.